# Unable to get values from a GET request

Tags: python-3.x, get, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website to extract values.

I can text back in the response, but cannot see any of the values on the website in the response.

How do i get the values please ?

I have used basic code from stackoverflow as a test to explore the data. The code is posted below. It works on other sites, but not this site ?

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/253741/'
data = requests.get(url).text



with open('F:\\webScrapeFolder\\out.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(data.encode("utf-8"), file=f)


print('--- end ---')
```

There is no error message.
The file is written correctly.
However, i do not see any of the numbers ?!?

Comment: is `requests.get(url).status_code == 200`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this

```
url ="https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/253741/?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true"
```

and try to get the response and still if you cannot get what is expected can you brief more on what is needed

Comment: This works.  I notice that you added `switchLocale=y` and also `siteEntryPassthrough=true` ... how would i know to add this additional part to the URL please ?